# Get NullPointerException when using ObjectInputStream instead of BufferedReader

Tags: java, sockets, io

I am trying to establish a connection to a socket server that reads and writes using Object Streams. I am able to send objects to the server, but when I try use the ObjectInputStream to listen for a response, I get an error.

**note** debug.debug() is a wrapper around sout

My client:

```
public class Client {

    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;

    Debug debug = new Debug();

    /**
     * Connect to a local socket server and start IO streams
     * @param port Port to connect to
     */
    public void connect(Integer port) {

        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
            debug.debug("CONNECTED", "GREEN");

            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                try {
                    handleResponse(in.readObject());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    debug.debug("CONNECTION_LOST", "ERROR");
                    break;
                }
            }
            connect(8080);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            debug.debug("Could not connect to host", "ERROR");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                connect(8080);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                debug.debug("Sleep failed", "ERROR");
            }
        }
    }

    public void out(Model model) {

        try {
            out.reset();
            out.writeObject(model);
            debug.debug("Sent serialized object to server. [" + model.model + "]");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debug.debug("Could not write object", "ERROR");
        }
    }

    private void handleResponse(Object model) {

        if (model instanceof User)
            if (((User)model).authorized)
//                ((User)model).dispatch();
                debug.debug("accepted");
    }

    public void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        connect(8080);
    }
}
```

Login class:

```
public final class Login extends JComponent implements Dispatcher {

    Button login;
    TextField email;
    PasswordField password;

    User User = new User();

    Debug debug = new Debug();

    public Login() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        login = new Button("LOGIN", null);
        email = new TextField();
        password = new PasswordField();

        login.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (!email.getText().equals(""))
                if (!password.getText().equals("")) {
                    User.email = email.getText();
                    User.password = password.getText();
                    Admin.Socket.out(User);
                }
        });

        build();
    }

    public void userAuthorized() {

        debug.debug("authorized");
    }

    public void build() {

        GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

        constraint.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        constraint.gridx = 0;
        constraint.gridy = 0;
        constraint.gridheight = 1;
        constraint.gridwidth = 2;

        constraint.ipadx = 250;
        add(email, constraint);
        constraint.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
        constraint.gridy = 1;
        add(password, constraint);
        constraint.gridy = 2;
        constraint.ipadx = 100;
        constraint.ipady = 15;
        add(login, constraint);
    }
}
```

This gives me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I call the out method. However if I instead use a BufferedReader to listen, then everything works as expected.

```
    public void connect(Integer port) {

        try{
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
            debug.debug("CONNECTED", "GREEN");

            // BufferedReader instead of ObjectInputStream
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                try {
//                    handleResponse(in.readObject());
                    debug.debug(in.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    debug.debug("CONNECTION_LOST", "ERROR");
                    break;
                }
            }
            connect(8080);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            debug.debug("Could not connect to host", "ERROR");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                connect(8080);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                debug.debug("Sleep failed", "ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call out, the server receives the sent object. However now I cannot listen for objects returned by the server. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at socket.Client.out(Client.java:59)
    at applications.admin.components.Login.lambda$new$0(Login.java:48)
    at applications.admin.components.Login$$Lambda$6/500977346.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**EDIT** Server:

```
public class Server {

    static Debug debug = new Debug();

    /**
     * Start a socket server
     */
    public void listen(Integer port, TextArea logs) {

        logs = logs != null ? logs : new TextArea();

        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            debug.debug("Server is running", "GREEN", logs);

            while (true) {
                Handler handler;
                try {
                    handler = new Handler(server.accept(), logs);
                    Thread client = new Thread(handler);
                    client.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    debug.debug("CLIENT_ACCEPT Failed", "ERROR", logs);
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            debug.debug("SERVER_START Failed", "ERROR", logs);
        }
    }

    public void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        listen(8080, null);
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public class Handler implements Runnable {

    Socket client;
    Debug debug = new Debug();

    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;

    TextArea logs;

    User user = new User();

    /**
     * Client instance running on new thread
     *
     * @param client Client Socket
     */
    Handler(Socket client, TextArea logs) {

        this.client = client;
        this.logs = logs;
        debug.debug("CLIENT_CONNECTED", "GREEN", logs);
    }

    /**
     * Listen to the client Stream and respond
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                try {
                    try {
                        handleResponse((User) in.readObject());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        debug.debug("Unable to read object", "ERROR", logs);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    debug.debug("CLIENT_DISCONNECTED", "ERROR", logs);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debug.debug("CONNECTION_FAILED", "ERROR", logs);
        }
    }

    private void handleResponse(User user) {

        debug.debug("Received serialized object from client. [" + user.model + "]", logs);

        if (user.auth()) {
            try {
                out.reset();
                out.writeObject(user);
                debug.debug("server: AUTHORIZED", "GREEN", logs);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                debug.debug("Couldn't write object", "ERROR", logs);
            }
        } else {
            debug.debug("server: UNAUTHORIZED", "ERROR", logs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact exception message and the stack trace.

Comment: I know this. That is where I call the out method.

Comment: What does `handleResponse(...)` do ? It is your own method or the one in Apache utils ?

Comment: This is my own method. It simply logs out the value of a variable within the object returned from the server. I can replace it with `System.out.println(((User)in.readObject()).email);`

Comment: Is that a multi-threaded application and are `Client.out(...)` and `Client.connect(...)` called in parallel?

Comment: It is multithreaded but client.out is only called once a connection has been made. Please note both the server and the client no longer read or write unless I use BufferedReader.

Comment: What is the exact line where the exception occurs? Can `user` be `null`? Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Is `out` field `volatile`? Can you show all the relevant code?

Comment: It occurs at `Socket.Client.out`, User cannot be null. I have definitely tried to debug. All I can determine is that when I instantiate a new ObjectInputReader, then all communication fails

Comment: I will update my question with all classes that are associated.

Comment: `readLine()` returns null at end of stream. You aren't detecting that case. NB Not all `IOExceptions` mean that the client disconnected.

Comment: Don't use recursion as a retry technique, and don't call methods that rely on side-effects of other methods until those methods have returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how the `Client` and `Login` classes are connected, so I'll just guess.

`ObjectInputStream` constructor, as said in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream-java.io.InputStream-), "will block until the corresponding `ObjectOutputStream` has written and flushed the header". So your `Client.connect()` thread freezes at the `in = new ObjectInputStream(...)` line and doesn't set values for `in` and `out`. (Actually, the server thread also freezes for the same reason, so you have a deadlock.) Meanwhile, `Login` thread tries to write something to `out`, but `out` is still `null`, so it gets a `NullPointerException`.

Why doesn't this happen with `BufferedReader`? It doesn't block in the constructor, so the thread just continues execution, sets non-`null` value for `out` and everyone is happy.

Fix: create `ObjectOutputStream` first and flush it, so that `ObjectInputStream` on the other end doesn't have to wait. In other words, change

```
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

to

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

in both client and server.

---

Another problem, which you may face after you've fixed the first one, is that `Client.out` field is not `volatile` and there is no obvious synchronization, so `Login` thread may see `null` there even after `out` is set to a non-`null` value in `Client.connect()` thread.
So I suggest you make `Client.out` field `volatile` (and maybe `Client.in` too).